# jquery keep popup and be able to fire ajax request inside the popup

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, events, click

I have a div container which class is `popup` and when i click on it, it wont close which is what i want it to do

but inside i also have some anchor tags for some ajax requests which doesn't execute since i have return false on the parent container

```
$(".popup").click(function(e){
   return false;
});
```

how can i make the ajax requests work and still keep the popup visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so clear with you question, but do you mean something like this:

```
$(".popup").click(function(e) {
    alert("Parent");
    e.preventDEfault();
});
$("#test").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("Clicked"); //run ajax request
});
```

See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvrTk/7/)

Comment: Ewwww.  Use `console.log()` :P

Answer (score 0):

Put your `return` statement at the end of the callback. Anything after it will not run.

Or, if the purpose is to prevent the event's default action, use `e.preventDefault()` instead.

Comment: i want to keep the popup and be able to fire the anchor ajax requests inside the popup without it closing...

Comment: You're talking too generally. You will need to edit the question to show precisely what is happening - or, better still, set up a Fiddle. You asked how to avoid the situation whereby the return is preventing execution of other callback code - that's what I answered.